# How to print each letter index using a reference variable

Tags: python, string, list

So I have a variable contains a sentence `text = 'hello world`, and also a variable contains every alphabet (using string library) `lowercase_alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase` (in short it's contain every letters alphabet but in lowercase).

And the problem is, how I can print each letter index from the `text` variable using `lowercase_alphabet` variable as an reference.

Here's the code:

```
import string

text = 'hello world'
lowercase_alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

# the result should be like this
# 8, 5, 12, 12, 15
# 23, 15, 18, 12, 4
```

Comment: `str.index` has what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the index in `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```py
for word in text.split(" "):
    print(", ".join(str(lowercase_alphabet.index(char) + 1) for char in word))
```

Comment: what does `", "` it mean?

Comment: @fiftythreeR ", ".join() is really `str.join`. When you join a sequence, you are essentially concatenating each member in the list by whatever that string is. You can put different separators in there yourself to test that.